# How to count the series in a scatter chart

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 2016 (O365?) makes all markers in a chart as circles. I want to make them different. The idea is to determine the number of series in a chart and make the changes within a `For ...To (number of series) Next` loop. I have no idea how to find the *number of series*.

```vb
Sub aCountLines()

    With ActiveChart
        Dim lngSeriesCount As Long
        lngSeriesCount = .ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
        MsgBox (lngSeriesCount)
    End With
End Sub
```

Error Message: the item with the specified name wasn't found

Comment: If your ActiveChart is an embedded chart and not a chart sheet, you will experience an error.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out myself that something is wrong in my code. It doesn't work for both embedded and chart sheet. I'm gently asking how to make it working? - Thank you.

Comment: is this your full code?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count instead.

Comment: I did this and got a count of zero in chart that had 19 series items in it.